# Why textbox value doesn't show anything?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have used this script to retrieve data from database to textbox. it alert the url but not retrieving or showing anything in textboxes. here is my script used in views...

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ItemId').blur(function () {
                var v = $('#ItemId').val();
                var url = "RawMaterials/Search/" + v;
                alert("Testing syetem:"+url);
                  $.getJSON(url, null, function (data, status) {

                    $.each(data, function (index, C) {
                        $("#ItemName").val(C.ItemName);
                        $("#MeasuringUnit").val(C.MeasuringUnit);
                        $("#Rate").val(C.Rate);
                        $("#Quantity").val(C.Quantity);
                        $("#BagSz").val(C.BagSz);
                    });
                });
            });

        });

    </script>
}
```

And controller is...

```
public JsonResult Search(string id = null)
        {
            if (id != null)
            {
                var sresult = db.Query<tblItem>("Where ItemId=" + id).ToList<tblItem>();
                return Json(sresult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
```

Comment: Is that a typo in the question or the code - $.getjeson ?

Comment: before you do anything else. change db.Query<tblItem>("Where ItemId=" + id) to work with curly bracers... "Where ItemId = {0}" , id.
this is a major security breach with sql injections

Comment: I have solve this. Edited This line only var url = "/RawMaterials/Search/" + v;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have some problem in this line

```
   $.getjeson(url, null, function (data, status);
```

j should be capital in $.getjson

change it as

```
$.getJson(url, null, function (data, status);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#ItemId').blur(function () {
                    var v = $('#ItemId').val();
                    var url = '@Url.Action("Search","RawMaterials")';
                    alert("Testing syetem:"+url);
                   $.ajax({
                      type:"POST",
                      url : url,
                      data:{id:v},
                      success:function(data){
                        // your code
                      }
                   });
                });

            });

        </script>
```